# Count of child in Coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I need to find count of children based on logic.

I have table A,  it has two relationship B and C. Now i need to find count of B and C.
Count  = No of B * NO  of C.

Data:

```
A1 
{
    {
    B1a
    },
    {
    C1a,
    C1b
    }
},
A2:
{
    {
    B2a,
    B2b
    },
    {
    C2a,
    C2b
    }
}
```

Total Count = 6

i have tried with following

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"A" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSArray *allObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
NSInteger totalCount= 0;

for(A *a in allObjects)
{
    NSInteger countOfB = [a.B count];
    NSInteger countOfc = [a.C count];
    totalCount = totalCount + (countOfB * countOfc);
}
```

This is work fine. But when i have 10000 records it is taking more time. Please suggest me if any alternative ways.

Comment: Try maybe the other way, using a `NSPredicate`, fetching `B` and `C` object which have a `A` object (in their relationship inverse) and using `@count`.

Comment: can you please provide some sample code use @count. I have tried with NSExpression but this give count of B and count of c. If i consider above example: 3 (count of B) * 4 (count of C) = 12. This is giving wrong value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do the multiplication on demand. Each time an `A` instance has the relationship to `B` or `C` changed, calculate the product and store it in a new attribute on `A`. Now to fetch your total count you can use only a single fetch (returning dictionary type) and then `@sum` (using the array with a collection operator) and none of the objects need to actually be loaded into memory.

Consider using KVO to monitor for relationship changes and trigger the update to your product.